# how to make List of of mutable objects Immuatable

Tags: java, collections, immutability

Hi I was asked this interview question that you have list of objects in an immutable class, Is the class really immuatable, what can be modified and how can you prevent it. I gave the below solution.

```
public final class A{
   final List<B> listOfB; // B is mutable

   public List<B> getListOfB(){
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.listOfB);
   }
}
```

now he says even after getting getListOfB() he can change the 'B' instances and wanted me to avoid this also. Then i said.

```
public List<B> getListOfB(){
   List<B> ret;
   for(B b: this.listOfB){
       ret.add(b.clone()); // basically make a deep copy of 'b' for return list
   }
   return ret;
}
```

The interviewer did not respond back anything saying it was right or wrong.

This solution definately works. But is there a better way of doing it, my approach is very clumsy and requires to too much additional memory.

PS: Assume B cannot be made immutable.

Comment: If `B` cannot be made immutable then returning a list of clones is your only option -- provided that you _can_ clone them

Comment: In your example, class A is not immutable, because you do not guarantee that you really own the Objects in `listOfB` - it doesn't really matter, if you clone the elements in `getListOfB()`. You would need to clone the elements of `listOfB` inside the constructor of class A instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `B` is an interface or an implementation of the interface `A`, you could wrap each element of `listOfB` by using a `java.net.Proxy` of `B` or `A` respectively, which intercepts all modifying calls by throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead.

More detailed, replace each item of the `listOfB` with a `java.net.Proxy` wrapped instance, implementing `A`. Then whenever someone fetches an item of `listOfB`, he will obtain the wrapped instance instead. Whenever someone calls a setter on such a wrapped item, intercept the call and throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Hope you have an idea what I mean. It's basically what `Collections.unmodifiableXXX()` does. If you have knowledge of all methods which may modify the state of an item of `listOfB`, `B` does not have to be an `POJO`. Just make sure that your wrapper replaces all modifying methods by throwing an exception.

Comment: Why are you assuming it as POJO? Class can also contain public data members.

Comment: I think it is of no relevance, if you have not to wrap generic types. As long as you know everything about `B` it has not to be a `POJO` at all. My fault. Hence I improved my answer a bit.